# Automated/scheduled task fails, if no user is logged in

Tags: c#, xml, batch-processing, windows-server-2012-r2

I have a scheduled task which starts an .exe, that I programmed myself. If I logon to our server and start the .exe myself, everything works fine. The program connects to our database, downloads files from the internet, writes some data to xml-files on the hdd and does some updates on our database.
But if the exe is started at night, with a windows scheduled task with full permissions, the program crashes. I have no chance to see the error. I implemented some logging, but the log files are always empty. It seems to crash right at the start of the program. What's weird is, that I have other programs that also run at night and do the exact same thing. Download files from the web, store them at the local hdd, update our databse. And thex work fine. The only difference is that, they're not modifying xml-files on the server. Could that be the difference?
any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: No, that's not the difference. Add verbose logging to the scheduled task itself. Check its history. Did it run? How do you know it *crashed*? Why should you *see* the error? Did you check the Event Viewer? Have you added unhandled exception logging?  Does the program require a UI perhaps, and crashes when it *can't* create it?

Comment: Have task run as admin.  The environmental variables aren't set the same as when you run the application when you are logged in.  You are running from a windows System credentials.  Try running the application as an admin and see if it runs properly to verify that changing the task to run as admin will work.

Answer (score 0):

(1) The first thing to check would be the "Security Options" for your task
[image: Task Scheduler Security Options]

(2) Check the "History" tab to see what time the job has run and see whether it has logged any failures.

(3) For the Action, check the "Start in" path[image: Action properties]

(4) Check the Event Viewer. It is likely to have details of the exception.

In my experience, the Scheduled task failures are most likely due to 
(1) user security / permission issues
(2) Path issues

Comment: the "start in"-parameter could be the problem as it was not set (didnt even know that it exists) gonna try it now and see what happens!

Comment: Did not work unfortunately. Where in the event viewer would I see an error regarding the schedules task? I am quite new to windows server and those things. Thanks a lot

Comment: Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application
Look for log entries around your expected task run time

Comment: What is your "Security Option" setting ?

Comment: Its "run whether user is logged in or not". that was the first thing I did wrong, after that 2 or 3 batches worked flawlessly.